# Coupon printing

Tags: windows

I can no longer print any coupons.  How do I tell what Window version I am running?  Yes, I am lay on the computer here.  I've also installed Java, but when I go looking for it, it's not listed on my computer programlist.

Comment: Press the Windows key. If there is an entry "Devices and Printers" you have Windows 7. Open it and you should see "Printers and Faxes".  Right-click your printer and select "Troubleshoot". Tell us what is happening then.

Comment: So, what do you want to print coupons in? Using which application? Why can't you do it anymore?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Easiest way to find out if user has either Windows 7 or Vista (through telephone support)?](http://superuser.com/questions/401370/easiest-way-to-find-out-if-user-has-either-windows-7-or-vista-through-telephone)

Answer (score 2):

**To Check Your OS Version (Windows):**

1. Click *Start*
2. Right Click *My Computer*
3. Select *Properties*

It should be listed there, mine looks like this:

[image: Windows Version]

**Make Sure your Printer is Installed**

1. Click *Start*
2. Click *Devices and Printers*
3. Let us know what is listed under *Printers and Faxes*, it should match your current printer (model number should be on the printer).

*If it is listed*

Troubleshoot like @gentlesea suggested

*If it is not listed*

Verify that it is on and plugged in.  You could update the drivers, if you let me know your OS version and the printer model/make and I will give you a link to them.

Answer (score 1):

You can open the command line and type

`ver`

or for a more user friendly information ...

`systeminfo | findstr /B /C:"OS Name" /C:"OS Version"`

> OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 7 Ultimate
>
> OS Version:                6.1.7600 N/A Build 7600

Comment: You don't honestly expect a layperson to do this, do you? I know of many who have no idea even what the command prompt is, or how to access it.

Answer (score 0):

1. click "Start"
2. If you see an option marked "Run", click it.  If not, you should see a box labelled "search programs and files".
3. Enter this command "cmd".
4. You should see a window that is mostly black, with a prompt that says something that ends with this Character: ">".  I'll use "blah blah" in what follows.
5. Enter the ver command as follows:  blah blah> ver
   This tells you the windows version.  but it isn't easy to read.
6. enter the java verison command, as follows:  blah Blah>java -version
   This tells you the java version number, or else it gives you an error.
7. enter the exit command as follows:  blah blah> exit
   This closes the black window.

Even if you have java installed, your browser might still have java disabled.